# How to add `metric_relabel_configs` from a separate file via `file_sd_configs`?

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics

I have a `vmagent` configuration where I can only add extra configuration options via separate files.

[image: prom.yml]

Let's take this file to be static, as in I can not modify this file.

I can only add my own configuration in `file.yml` which looks like this.

[image: file.yml]

This configuration does not work, removing `metric_relabel_configs` makes the configuration work. How can I add `metric_relabel_configs` from a file config?

This is the error I get.

[image: promtool check config error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described, you basically cannot.

`metric_relabel_config` is defined at the job level as documented in [scrape_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) section of Prometheus ; and VictoriaMetrics [documents the same](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#relabeling) behavior.

So you have to have access to the scrape configuration.

It looks like a odd constraint as `headers`, `scheme` and `metrics_path` are very common configuration points.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thank you because I can now stop spending time on this.

Comment: `file_sd_configs` is rather intended as a generic interface to external service discovery. It is not a way to extend the configuration file. There is a features to allow better config split: see https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1559. Now it all depends on your setup.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I don't have control over the main config file, another team handles it. There are other ways to solve my problem, this was one of them but no problem if it's a dead end.